# python server configuration. IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied(Permission denied to ...log.file)

Tags: python, server, windows-server

Please help me with python server configuration. I am getting an error when I execute .pyw file in cmd with python command i got an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied(Permission denied to ...log.file)
```

I'm an administrator. My OS: `win server 2012r2 64-bit`, python 2.7.9 (anaconda 2.2.0 32-bit),python 2.7 cx_oracle-5.1.2-10g 32-bit,ora client 12.1.0 32-bit.

Answer (score 2):

That exception is quite clear about what's going on. Check if mentioned log file is writable by user running  .pyw file. If that file does not exist check permissions for parent directory.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. now another error occurred.: InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle.

Comment: For anybody to help you more information is needed. Please create another question with better description of what your python application is doing and problem you are experiencing. And don't forget to mention what you've already tried to solve it ;)

Comment: Hello Beezz, I created another question "Python server configuration" with detailed description of my python problems. Could you please help me? Thank you.